# Сложение элементов символьного массива.Длинная арифметика

Tags: c, массивы

Пытаюсь сложить элементы символьного массива , чтобы реализовать сложение в длинной арифметики.Но пока использую массив с маленьким количеством элементов , чтобы проследить , где что сломается. Пока пишу только с неотрицательными числами , чтобы меньше путаницы.
Объявил массивы

```
          char A[N], B[N], C[N];
```

Соответственно обнуляю их

```
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
    B[i] = 0;
    C[i] = 0;
}
```

Теперь заполняю первый массив,делаю это с конца

```
          i = 0;
while ((A[N - i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Тут возникает первый вопрос : Мог бы использовать EOF ,но не получается(ну тип  CTRL+Z все равно отстой какой-то, будто это нажатие записывается в массив как отдельный элемент ) ,окей ,стал использовать '\n' (enter нажимаю). но все равно подозрение , что код этого символа записывается в массив и потом только завершается цикл 
Поэтому сделал это:

```
              for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i] == '\n')
        A[i] = 0;
}
```

Со вторым массивом аналогично

А теперь само сложение , идея как у сложения в столбик : если результат сложения меньше равен 9 , то сохраняю в 3 массив, иначе один в уме(и его на следующий элемент) и в нынешний записываю только получившиеся единицы ,

```
    for (i = N; i > 0; i--) {

    if ((A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') - '0' <= 9)
    {
        C[i] = (A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') - '0';
        r = 0;
    }
```

Ну да , все таки реализацию  с "один в уме не догоняю как реализовать"

НО с обычными числами , не выходящими за девятку по сумме должно же работать? 
Еще одни вопрос по поводу этого

```
            (A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') - '0'
```

Я так понимаю , что тут смотрится по коду из аскии таблицы, например код числа 3
это 51 и минус код нуля , то есть 48 и того нужная тройка , я правильно понмаю ?
то же и с B ну например так 2 , а потом  3+2 и из общего разность , то е сть кода 5(53 вычесть 48 и получить нужные 5 )

Надесюь я правильно понял

и Последнее - вывод

```
      for (i = N; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", C[i]);
    }
```

Понятия не имею почему на выходе какой-то мусор 
В чем проблема , как грамотно реализовать сложение в длинной арифметике?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
const int N = 10;
void main(void)
{
char A[N], B[N], C[N];
int c = 0, i = 0, r = 0, j = 0, l = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
    B[i] = 0;
    C[i] = 0;
}

i = 0;
while ((A[N - i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
    i = i + 1;
    j = j + 1;
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i] == '\n')
        A[i] = 0;
}

i = 0;

while ((B[N - i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
    i = i + 1;
    l = l + 1;
}
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (B[i] == '\n')
        B[i] = 0;
   }

    for (i = N; i > 0; i--) {

    if ((A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') - '0' <= 9)
    {
        C[i] = (A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') - '0';
        r = 0;
    }

    for (i = N; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", C[i]);
    }
    _getch();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Ну я бросал вам вариант - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753946/195342 - что в нем не так?..

Comment: `(A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') + '0'`  "я правильно понмаю ?" - да

Comment: @Harry,хочу найти и понять ошибки в своей реализации

Comment: @Igor, не понятно , зачем + 0 в конце , разве получится нужное число ?К тому же я уже писал с +0, ничего не срабатывало всё равно

Comment: Вы уже задавали почти такой же вопрос. Почему бы не воспользоваться советами 1) вычитать '0' сразу при вводе 2) в цикле, где вычисляете сумму считать ее сразу с учетом переноса (т.е. складывать не 2 числа а 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка - один-то `'0'` надо обратно прибавить:

```
C[i] = (A[i] - '0') + (B[i] - '0') + '0';
```

В таблице ASCII символов цифры расположены рядом в таком порядке: `0123456789`.

Код двойки (какой бы он ни был) минус код нуля - равно 2. Код тройки минус код нуля - равно 3. Складываем - получается 5. Но это число пять, чтобы получить код символа `5`, надо добавить код нуля.

Не торопитесь складывать десятизначные числа. Начните со сложения однозначных.

Comment: Ну ,например, элемент массива А - это 3 ,его код в аскии таблице 51, то есть из 51-48 = 3 , это в первой скобке , во второй ,скажем,5(его код  53) , то есть 53-48=5, потом складываю 3 и 5 = 8 , а потом из кода восьмерки(56) вычесть код нуля (48) и получить обратно 8, арзве не так ?

Comment: "К тому же я уже писал с +0," - значит неправильно писали.

Comment: @Elvin Да, еще хотел сказать. Вы - молодец, что пытаетесь сами написать код для решения этой задачи. Не сдавайтесь.